# Opendaylight Fluorine-SR1 NO DLUX APP web user interface?

Tags: opendaylight

i can't find Opendaylight Fluorine-SR1 include  DLUX web user interface?
anyone knows?
THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DLUX was not active or maintained, thus removed from recent releases including
Fluorine. If you need DLUX, you'll have to use an older release.

Comment: @Jiang If you have some coding experience with JavaScript, there's also the option to pick up DLUX and port it to Fluorine. There's quite some interest in having DLUX survive, so if all parties interested would join forces, maybe it would be possible to keep the project alive.